# How to estimate the frictional losses of a car drivetrain?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, friction, simulations, estimation

I'm making a car driving video game which uses real engine torque curves, gear ratios and other physical attributes as parameters to simulate the motion of a specific car.

The problem here is that I don't quite understand the way the frictional torque of transmission components (gearbox, drive shafts etc.) builds up as the car accelerates through gears. I'm not trying to calculate the torque caused by individual components in the drivetrain but instead setting an imaginary parameter that would reflect the overall friction properties of a specific transmission eg. setting a higher value for a heavy-duty vehicle transmission than for a small passenger car.

What I'm seeking here is a simplified function to estimate the torque applied to drive wheels caused by drivetrain power losses. I have so far tried using a constant value for the above-mentioned torque. That gives somewhat realistic acceleration having wide open throttle and running the engine at maximum power range (typically shifting up near engine redline). However, the simulated car struggles to accelerate at a lower "casual driving" rpm range (2000-3500 rpm for a petrol engine) and slows down at a relatively gradual uphill road when compared to the real life counterpart of the simulated car.

Comment: Rather than applying a constant loss torque value, it might be more correct to apply an efficiency ratio of the drivetrain losses. That ratio would be independent of vehicles/engines sizes.

https://x-engineer.org/automotive-engineering/drivetrain/transmissions/drivetrain-losses-efficiency/

Comment: Aren't the drive train losses simply the difference between the horsepower  developed at the engine crankshaft and the horsepower delivered to the wheel(s)?

Comment: I'm afraid both the drivetrain efficiency and the output torque are unknown while I would need to know one of them to define the other. I think a simple reference of how the efficiency changes as the car gains more speed eg. the gears and shafts rotate faster could solve the problem.

Comment: For the drive train, are you willing to "lump" all frictional losses together, which includes friction in the engine, drive shaft, transmission, differential, and tire drag?

Comment: In fact I have already implemented codes engine friction and tire drag separately since they were pretty straightforward. Thus I'm thinking of a simplified formula to estimate gearbox, drive shaft and differential friction as a whole (though gearbox friction torque transmitted to the drive wheels is also affected by the effective gear ratio).

Answer (score 0):

[image]

You can use this equation that transformed the engine torque to the wheel.

$M=I_H\,I_G\,M_{mot}$

Where

$I_G$ is the gear ratio  for manuell gear

Comment: I'm afraid that's only the equation for how gear ratios work.

Comment: No this equation transfer the engine torque to the wheels. I think this is what you need. The vehicle equation of motion is then $m\,a= M/r$ where r is the wheel Radius.

Comment: $I_G$ is the Gear ratio, and $I_H$ is the differential ratio

Comment: Please revise the original post. That equation doesn't take transmission frictional torque losses, which I'm asking about, into account.

Comment: I see, but anyway this is not realistic model, just a toys, so why you need the friction?